# If clause not working properly in cron while working OK in command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, sh

I'm trying to run a script that periodically checks the headers returned by a website and, if headers return 200 show headers first line, else just curl a file .

```
(date; htres=`curl -Is https://somedomayn.com | head -n 1`;if [ `echo $htres | cut -d " " -f 2` == 200 ]; then echo $htres; else curl https://somedomayn.com/tisfile.php; fi;printf "\n")
```

While executing it from command line seems to work fine, I'm having some issues when trying to make it work in crontab:

```
* * * * * (date; htres=`curl -Is https://somedomayn.com | head -n 1`;if [ `echo $htres | cut -d " " -f 2` == 200 ]; then echo $htres; else curl https://somedomayn.com/tisfile.php; fi;printf "\n") >> mylog.txt
```

It seems that the if-clause always evaluates false returning always the curl info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your shell code in a script and run this script with your cronjob to make it clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: Your problem _may_ be that cron is using an `sh` that doesn't support `==`. Try changing to a single equal sign.

Comment: Using a script as Cyrus suggests will also let you easily use a "shebang" to specify the parser as bash, witch solves the problem mentioned by Dennis. You can do it other ways, but a script can be cleanly maintained, put in a versioning repo, etc.